# Data not available error in dashboard

Tags: dashboard, custom-reports

I have a user A who created one report type and using that report type he created one report and stored in one report folder. The user A has given access to user B for the report folder as viewer. Secondly user created a dashboard and that is saved in a dashboard folder . The dashboard folder is also shared with the user B as Viewer permission. The Dashboard is placed on the home screen of user B. When the user B tries to click the dashboard, this is the error message the user is getting

> *"Data Not Available The data you were trying to access could not be
>   found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system
>   error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it,
>   please look at our support page. "*

But the user B can view the source report of the dashboard under report tabs and can perform a drill down operation successfully.

Could you please share your thoughts on  why the user B is unable to view the source report by clicking the dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which folder did you store it? When you create a dashboard and you save it you get to save that into one of the following folders.

1) My Personal Custom Reports
2) Unfiled Public Reports

I think you have stored your custom report in the "My Personal Custom Reports" folder and that is why the user B is unable to access it.

If that's what you did then the below solutions may be handy.

### Solution:

I think the following ways would work . Try them.

1) Create a new folder and publish those reports from the "My Personal Custom Reports" to this and then check with the user you wanted.

### or

2) Create a public group for each user, and then create a report folder for that user and share the folder to this new Public Group.